# cordova gamecenter callback functions are not called after auth

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using cordova-plugin-game-center plugin (https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-game-center) on an ionic (v4) project. I test it on an iPhone 7.

The plugin seems to work just fine as I get a greeting message after auth() call and I can also display the leaders board.

However, the auth() call is supposed to trigger the success or the fail function passed to it but nothing happens. Has anybody experienced a similar issue? It is already difficult to debug these plugins due to sandbox account settings, etc. so any pointer would be grately appreciated it.

The below is my authentication code:

```
// This is how I get access to the cordova plugin
declare let gamecenter;

authenticateGameCenter() {        
    let successCallback = function (user) {
        this.gameCenterAuthenticatedFlag = true;
    };

    let failureCallback = function (user) {
        this.gameCenterAuthenticatedFlag = false;
    };

    gamecenter.auth(successCallback, failureCallback );        
}
```

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: Hey can you show some of your code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Augustin, I added the code to make it more clear

Comment: Are you making sure you do this after deviceReady is fired?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kody. I call this function from this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {this.authenticateGameCenter();}

Comment: The funny thing is I got visually greeted by the GameCenter when I call the auth. Hence, I know it works but the callback is not fired so I cannot confirm if the auth was successful before showing the leader board.

Comment: I wanted to plea again to see if anyone has any pointers to this issue. I'd be ethernally grateful if you could help me out.